# how to minimize the response time for this query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table having list of football matches. it has columns like match_id, team a score, team 2 score, rounds, match_date etc.

I need all rows from database with highest margin of that round
margin is difference of team a score and team b score.

my query is

```
SELECT *,( SELECT MAX(ABS((z.home_score - z.away_score))) 
FROM tblform_matches z 
WHERE YEAR(z.match_date) = YEAR(tblform_matches.match_date) 
    AND z.round = tblform_matches.round ) as highest_margin 
from tblform_matches where some condtion
```

it is a simplified query where some condition is a large query string to select some specified matches according to filter.

currently there are around 5000 matches in database.

Due to sub-query my page is taking 4 more seconds to load.

there are 9 matches in each round and there are more than 20 rounds in every year

I am executing the above query for every team in php loop. I cant change this thing. as there are a lot of calculation for showing stats.

Sorry if my question is uncleared, I am here if I missed something as I am a new bee to stakoverflow

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add secondary indexes on tblform_matches.match_date & tblform_matches.round.

Comment: Sorry but, this table is used in other 15 modules and those are interrelated, So I am not allowed to make any change to database. I have only read permission to show the stats

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT MAX(ABS((m2.home_score - m2.away_score))) 
        FROM tblform_matches m2
        WHERE YEAR(m2.match_date) = YEAR(m.match_date) AND
              m2.round = m.round
       ) as highest_margin 
from tblform_matches m
where some condition;
```

Presumably, the best way to optimize this is to focus on . Oh well.  You will want the right indexes there.

Indexes are clearly the solution, but you have a problem because the of the `year` function.  And easy solution is to use indequalities:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT MAX(ABS((m2.home_score - m2.away_score))) 
        FROM tblform_matches m2
        WHERE m2.round = m.round
              (m2.match_date >= makedate(year(m.match_date), 1) and
               m2.match_date < makedate(year(m.match_date) + 1, 1)
              )                  
       ) as highest_margin 
from tblform_matches m
where some condtion;
```

The best index for the subquery is `tblform_matches(round, match_date, home_score, away_score)`.  The first two columns are used for the `where` clause. The second two for the `select`.

Note:  if you made two relatively minor changes to the data structure, this could work even better.  Add a column for the year of the match date (redundant, but important for indexing).  And, add a column for the absolute value of the difference between the scores.  Then the query would be:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT MAX(score_diff)
        FROM tblform_matches m2
        WHERE m2.round = m.round and m2.matchyear = m.matchyear
       ) as highest_margin 
from tblform_matches m
where some condtion;
```

The index on this query would be:  `tblform_matches(round, matchyear, score_diff)` and the lookup should be pretty fast.

EDIT:

You may get better performance with an explicit `join`:

```
SELECT m.*, m2.highest_margin
from tblform_matches m join
     (select MAX(ABS((m2.home_score - m2.away_score))) as highest_margin
      from tblform_matches m2
      group by year(m2.match_date), m2.round
     ) m2
     on year(m.match_date) = year(m2.match_date) and m2.round = m.round
where some condition;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, as I explained in previous comment I can't make any change to database. and your solution without indexing is not providing any significant boost up in page load. currently it is 8 seconds.

Comment: The main issue is when loop is going for first team it checks for every match for that round and calculate highest margin for every round, but when it executes for the second time it again calculates for the all rounds which it calculated for first team. it happens for every team